# Symfony Config: Array node or null

Tags: php, symfony, configuration, config

Some of the features of my bundle are optional. In order to configure them, I'd like to have the following two options. If I want to enable the feature:

```
foo:
  feature:
    mandatory1: 'bar'
    mandatory2: 'bar2'
```

However, if I decide to not use this specific feature, I'd like to set `feature` to be null:

```
foo:
  feature: ~
```

I currently have the following code:

```
// ...
    ->arrayNode('feature')
        ->defaultNull()
        ->children()
            ->scalarNode('mandatory1')
                ->isRequired()
                ->cannotBeEmpty()
                ->end()
            ->scalarNode('mandatory2')
                ->isRequired()
                ->cannotBeEmpty()
                ->end()
            ->end()
        ->end()
```

However, the `defaultNull()` call is not allowed. Is there any way I can achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I found the answer by myself. Copied from the [Symfony docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config/definition.html#optional-sections):

> If you have entire sections which are optional and can be enabled/disabled, you can take advantage of the shortcut `canBeEnabled()` and `canBeDisabled()` methods.